# Menu bar has disappeared 14.10 - nvidia

Tags: unity, nvidia, upgrade, 14.10, menu-bar

I had some issues on upgrade 14.04->14.10 that others have reported with nvidia drivers failing to update, but it was working fine.

I just rebooted and the menu bar is missing, there are desktop links to documents that do work although the menu boarder is missing. I can ssh in no problem.

I tried several recipes for resetting unity and nvidia drivers but so far no change in behavior - I suspect it is unity related given there is a display and it is just the menus that are missing.

How do I reset the unit menu/windowing system from the command line

Answer (score 0):

I just had that exact problem.  I solved it by reinstalling unity at the command line.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, this will open a terminal on TTY2.

Log in with your user name and password

Then enter the command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

After the install finished all was well for me

Comment: I think you mean "sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity"